# Dynamic CSS class inside ngFor

Tags: html, css, angular

Hi I'm working on pure css star rating but I'm having a hard time in its css class. When I'm hovering on the other rating star the first one or the first 5 star rating are hovering.

[image: this is my work]

Like in this picture I tried to rate on the second question but the first 5 star in the first question is also hovering. This is my code

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let x of evaluation_form; let i = index">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p style="font-size: 16pt">Name:<strong style="font-size: 16pt"> {{x.emp_name}}</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p style="font-size: 16pt">Position:<strong style="font-size: 16pt">{{x.position}}</strong></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let y of x.segments; let j = index" [@hideShowAnimator]="i == hideShowAnimator">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-5" style="font-size: 35pt; color: #3c8dbc;">{{ y.segment_name }}</div>
    <div *ngFor="let z of y.question_collection ; let o = index">
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-11">
          <strong style="font-size: 16pt">{{ z.question }}</strong>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-11">
            <fieldset class="rating">
              <input type="radio" id="star5" name="{{y.segment_name}}x{{z.q_id}}" value="5" (change)="changeRatingValue(i,j,o,5)" /><label for="star5"></label>
              <input type="radio" id="star4" name="{{y.segment_name}}x{{z.q_id}}" value="4" (change)="changeRatingValue(i,j,o,4)" /><label for="star4"></label>
              <input type="radio" id="star3" name="{{y.segment_name}}x{{z.q_id}}" value="3" (change)="changeRatingValue(i,j,o,3)" /><label for="star3"></label>
              <input type="radio" id="star2" name="{{y.segment_name}}x{{z.q_id}}" value="2" (change)="changeRatingValue(i,j,o,2)" /><label for="star2"></label>
              <input type="radio" id="star1" name="{{y.segment_name}}x{{z.q_id}}" value="1" (change)="changeRatingValue(i,j,o,1)" /><label for="star1"></label>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" (click)="hideShowAnimation(i)">
    <button class="button"><span>Next </span></button>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

And this is my css for styling my radio button

```
.rating {
  float: left;
}

.rating:not(:checked)>input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.rating:not(:checked)>label {
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  padding: 0 .1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 302%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #ddd;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #bbb, 2px 2px #666, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.rating:not(:checked)>label:before {
  content: '★ ';
}

.rating>input:checked~label {
  color: #f70;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #c60, 2px 2px #940, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: gold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px goldenrod, 2px 2px #B57340, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

*I just want to make my 5 rating dynamic in each question. I just want to know how to do it in Angular 2. Thanks in advance for help*

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want for some reason to implement it from scratch, why not consider an already existing solution which is flexible and configurable?

Have a look at this plugin

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-star-rating

Comment: I tried that before but I'm having an error with some version

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

My apologies for the angularJS answer provided by mistake. Here's the Angular version.

TLDR; Add a class on hover event and style for that class.

HTML

```
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" (mouseover)="z.active=true" (mouseout)="z.active=false" id="star5" name="{{y.segment_name}}x{{z.q_id}}" value="5" (change)="changeRatingValue(i,j,o,5)" />
    <label [ngClass]="{'active': z.active}" for="star5"></label>
...
</fieldset>
```

CSS

```
.rating:not(:checked)>label.active:hover,
.rating:not(:checked)>label.active:hover~label {
    color: gold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px goldenrod, 2px 2px #B57340, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

---

**AngularJS**

Try setting an `active` class on `ng-mouseover` and set the styles for that.

HTML

```
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" ng-mouseover="z.active=true" ng-mouseleave="z.active=false" id="star5" name="{{y.segment_name}}x{{z.q_id}}" value="5" (change)="changeRatingValue(i,j,o,5)" />
    <label ng-class="{active: z.active}" for="star5"></label>
...
</fieldset>
```

CSS

```
.rating:not(:checked)>label.active:hover,
.rating:not(:checked)>label.active:hover~label {
    color: gold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px goldenrod, 2px 2px #B57340, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

Comment: That's angularJS not angular

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: @Lihini thanks for response, sorry for late reply i tried your code but still the same :(((

Comment: What exactly does not work? Can you maybe post a plunkr sample?